# Binding a Parent DataContext from within an ItemTemplate in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, attached-properties

I got a problem binding an ItemTemplates Parent context inside an item template.

There are plenty of "workarounds" which only work in WPF (i.e. using `FindAncestor` and `AncestorType`). This are out of question, as it's not supported in Windows Store Apps.

Other solutions suggest using `ElementName`. While this works in Windows Store Apps, it's not an acceptable solution, as it reusable DataTemplates impossible.

One solution I did read about was using Attached Properties/Attached Behaviors, which sounds like the way to go and is a very generic and reusable method. But I couldn't make it work so far.

My current attempt is, to create a global Attached Property and access it in the  `ItemTemplate`.

```
public class GlobalProperties : DependencyObject
{
    public static object GetParentDataContext(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ParentDataContextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetParentDataContext(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ParentDataContextProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ParentDataContext.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentDataContextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ParentDataContext",
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(GlobalProperties), 
            new PropertyMetadata(null, ParentDataContextChanged));

    private static void ParentDataContextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetParentDataContext(d, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

And my XAML (simplified by inlining the DataTemplate within the ListViews XAML Code. It will be later stored outside in an DataTemplate.xaml file.

```
    <ListView 
        my:GlobalProperties.ParentDataContext="{Binding}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}"
        >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-1,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(my:GlobalProperties.ParentDataContext).Site.Styling.TagBackgroundColor}">
                        <!-- Item Related DataBindings -->      
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Where `my` is the namespace where my `GlobalProperties` is defined.

When I have a breakpoint in `ParentDataContextChanged` it's definitely called with the DataContext. But I can't get the XAML code to work to read it. The `Background` Xaml Property is always empty and the background always remains white (color saved in the `TagBackgroundColor` property is red).

Anyone know what's wrong with the code/attempt?

**update**
Also `Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(my:GlobalProperties.ParentDataContext).Site.Styling.TagBackgroundColor}"` doesn't work, since that's what there in most website that show attached properties for such a case.

**update 2**
Example of of the ViewModel for better clarification

```
public class QuestionsViewModel : ViewModel 
{
    // Site.Styling.BackgroundColor to be bound to certain ItemTemplate 
    // Properties, but don't have access to it from the ItemTemplate
    // because it has the context of one item from Questions
    public Site Site { get; set; };
    // Questions bound to ListView.DataSource > becomes Item's DataContext
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; };
}

public class Site 
{
    public Style Styling { get; set; }
}

public class Style 
{
    public string ForegroundColor { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string LinkColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think, creating a converter with dependency property will work in this case.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach, but not sure how it's going to work. Dependency Properties are tied to a specific element. Any working examples?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to above comment, I'm putting sample code.

Main.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="TempApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:converter="using:TempApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-1,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="ListItemDataTemplateGrid"                           
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <converter:ValueToBackgroundConverter x:Key="ValueToBackgroundConverter" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}" />
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueToBackgroundConverter}}">
                        <!--Your Content-->
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Main.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<TempList> ListDataSource = new List<TempList>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        FillList();           
    }

    private void FillList()
    {
        ListDataSource.Clear();
        ListDataSource.Add(new TempList { BgColor = "Red" });
        ListDataSource.Add(new TempList { BgColor = "Red" });
        MyList.ItemsSource = ListDataSource;
    }
}

public class TempList
{
    public string BgColor { get; set; }
}
```

ValueToBackgroundConverter.cs

```
class ValueToBackgroundConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public string BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor",
                                     typeof(string),
                                     typeof(ValueToBackgroundConverter), null
                                     );

        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
//I've used static colors but you can do manipulations to convert string to color brush
            if (BackgroundColor != null)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xA3, 0xCE, 0xDC));
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xE3, 0xF0, 0xF4));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't exactly address the problem I have. This one binds the Value within the ItemTemplate. I need to bind values which are defined in the ViewMoldel that's bind to the Page. If it were within the Items, I could simply bind it without the converter. I've added ViewModel example to better clarify it